# How to make sizeToFit ignore width?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using sizeToFit in a piece of code where I want it to ignore the width but just "size to fit" based on height. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the original bounds, and set the new bounds to have the old width after calling `-sizeToFit`.

```
CGRect oldBounds = someView.bounds;
[someView sizeToFit];
CGRect newBounds = someView.bounds;
newBounds.size.width = oldBounds.size.width;
someView.bounds = newBounds;
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use the sizeThatFits: method, and pass in a `CGSize` with the width you want and a value of `CGFLOAT_MAX` for the height. This is the recommended way to size multiline labels to a specific width for example.

This was recommended to me by an Apple engineer in response to a feature request I made for exactly the question you are asking.